# Error in parsing JSON in Nodejs from Posted data

Tags: json, node.js, jquery, http-headers

I have used this jquery ajax code to pass JSON:

```
var jsonObjects = [{id:1, name:"amit"}];

$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'http://localhost:8080',
 data: {
     jsonData: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects)
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   complete: function(validationResponse) {
  }
});
```

I have used this node js code to parse JSON data:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
response.writeHeader(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
});
 response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});

  var theUrl = url.parse(request.url);
  var queryObj = queryString.parse( theUrl.query );
  var obj = JSON.parse( queryObj.jsonData);
  console.log(obj[0].id)
 response.write(String(obj[0].id))
   response.end();
}).listen(8080,'127.0.0.1');
```

but it displays following error in console:

```
undefined:1
rn┴P║Eee
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
at Object.parse (native)
at Server.<anonymous> (C:\node\nodejs\node_modules\17-8-12\tracker.js:79:22)

at Server.emit (events.js:70:17)
at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1610:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:91:29)

at Socket.ondata (http.js:1506:22)
at TCP.onread (net.js:374:27)
```

Then the code stops..

Answer (score 1):

This section:

```
response.writeHeader(200, {
  "Content-Type": "text/plain"
});
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
```

Seems garbled: is that your real code? If so, remove the first three lines. If that doesn't fix it, `console.log` `request.url` first, then `queryObj.jsonData` and see if they're reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer for your issue but I would suggest checking out [Express](http://expressjs.com/) and the [bodyParser](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body) middleware.

They you can do something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.query.jsonData);
  res.send('return data here');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: A GET request doesn't have a body, so the poster is doing it the right way.